# How to repair /boot on LUKS encrypted harddrive?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, encryption, luks

I have a laptop with Xubuntu installed.

At install I chose the full disk encryption option.

But yesterday i accidentally dd-ed a DSL image to sda1 (/boot partition) instead to sdb1 (pendrive).

How can i repair my /boot ?

Comment: pls tell us your ubuntu version

Answer (score 12):

Hello I tested the following commands in my laptop - yeah I deleted everything in `/dev/sda1` and I got it working again - so here it is:

- Get a live-image and boot from it.

<s>- First lets get a clean `/dev/sda1` -
open **GParted**; reformat `/dev/sda1` with **ext2** and don't forget to confirm the changes and then set the **"boot" flag** (right click on the partition --> select "Manage Flags" --> check the box next to "boot" [this automatically causes the "esp" flag to be set to] --> click the "Close" button).</s>  (this was due to "dd-ed a DSL image to sda1" in OP post)

- Now we will prepare everything to `chroot` into the installed system and then we will switch into it (via `chroot`):

  ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt
   sudo vgscan --mknodes
   sudo vgchange -ay
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
   for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
   sudo chroot /mnt
  ```
- Okay let's <s>delete and</s> reinstall GRUB:
  `grub-install /dev/sda` 
  <s>`apt purge grub-common` (have your terminal in fullscreen-mode due to ncurses), this might ask you if it shall delete everything - select yes; now lets reinstall it with `apt install grub-pc` here select `/dev/sda` when asked.</s>
- Lastly we need to reinstall a kernel to get the needed **initrd.img-*** and **vmlinuz-*** images into "/boot/". We get currently-installed kernels with `apt list --installed linux-image-*` and now we reinstall this kernel with `apt install linux-image-[version-numbers]-generic --reinstall` - don't forget to exchange the brackets with an actual version number.
- Almost done; exit chroot with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>, or just type `exit`, and then reboot (via GUI menus or with `sudo reboot`)!

## Used resources:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1432656.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: thx this post helped me again!

Comment: Great answer! One additional issue that I needed to fix after that: The reformat of sda1 lead to a different uuid for that partition. So I needed to change the uuid in fstab after this procedure.

Comment: I love you man.

Comment: Btw how do you copy/paste in a shell? I resorted to taking a pic of the uuid.

Comment: I would run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` instead of purging grub-common and reinstalling grub-pc.

Comment: What Marius says works; I tried this answer on Xubuntu 20.04. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918021/encrypted-custom-install/918030#918030) is another good resource.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this to rescue an encrypted Manjaro install, and I had to modify [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/844231/841495)'s commands slightly for them to work.

1️⃣ Instead of mounting the drive's boot partition to `/mnt/boot`, I had to mount it to `/mnt/boot/efi`. Otherwise, GRUB would complain that it can't find the EFI partition.

2️⃣ I had to add `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` to the for loop (credit to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418913/367861)). Without this, GRUB would not recognize the `chroot`ed system as being booted in UEFI mode, though it was:

```
# grub-install /dev/drive
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory.
```

The drive details:

```
# "drive" is the encrypted Manjaro drive we need to reinstall GRUB on

$ lsblk -o NAME,UUID,SIZE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,MODEL,SERIAL
drive             931.5G
├─drivep1 UUID1   300M     vfat          # EFI partition
├─drivep2 UUID2   922.4G   crypto_LUKS   # /
└─drivep3 UUID3   8.8G     crypto_LUKS   # SWAP
```

#### The version of the commands that worked for me:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/drivep2 drive_crypt
vgscan --mknodes
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/mapper/drive_crypt /mnt
mount /dev/drivep1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
chroot /mnt
```

Once `chroot`ed in, run:

```
grub-install /dev/drive
pacman -S linux?? # replace "??" with whatever kernel version already exists 
                  # or is desirable
```

Exit `chroot` (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> or run `exit`), reboot (`systemctl reboot`), and try to boot in to the rescued drive by selecting its entry in the UEFI!