# Full Disk Encryption and Custom Partitioning on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

How can I use Full Disk Encryption (LUKS) with a custom partition scheme on Ubuntu 18.04?

Full Disk Encryption seems to be allowed on installation only if the option "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" is selected.

On the Custom Partitioning Mode, when showing partitions, no option with encryption let me mount the root (/) filesystem.

Comment: You can encrypt individual partitions (not LUKS, not during install), or you can encrypt the entire disk (LUKS, during install).

Comment: @user535733: "you can encrypt the entire disk (LUKS, during install)" - yes, but then partitioning is default (1 partition /; you cannot customized partitions)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1199213/47073