# How can I install GRUB to an external device to boot an internal FDE install?

Tags: grub2, encryption, bootloader, mate, nvme

I have a Dell Latitude e7250 which doesn't officially support NVME via UEFI and thus has no bootstrapping for it. I installed a Toshiba RC100 2242 NVME drive in an M.2 slot designated for WWAN cards and it does indeed function as a drive just fine. So I need to install my bootloader to a device that can be recognised by the UEFI. I can either use a small USB key or an MSATA drive.

I've had no luck with the installer in trying to designate another device for the bootloader when using full disk encryption. I have managed to use the manual partitioner for an unencrypted install with the bootloader on a flash drive but this isn't desirable. Specifically I'm trying to use Ubuntu MATE 18.04 or 19.04.

I'm wondering if there's a technical limitation that I'm missing. If strictly necessary I'll just fall back to an encrypted home partition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's something that might work. Check out my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/918030/606758). Grab the LGMP script, using that for install. When you get to the partition-assignment stage of install, ignore the instructions in my script and select your external device for the `/boot` partition. Also select that external device for installation of the bootloader. I've not tried this, but it should work.

Comment: I've finally run through it and it looks very promising, have had to make a couple of extra deductions but now I'm stuck with a broken grub-mkconfig not completing, I'll have to get to the bottom of that. Very much appreciate your info, it's helped me understand the process a lot better - it must be close now.

Comment: After tearing my hair out, looks like update-grub's stall was non critical and it somehow built the grub.cfg just fine, though I was sure I could see problems on manual inspection. Problem solved, excellent work!