# Update 16.04 to 18.04 broken due to 0 bytes in /boot, not yet rebooted

Tags: boot, upgrade, reboot

So, stupidly, I neglected to clean up /boot before running update from 16.04 to 18.04. All seemed to go well until right at the end I got the warning of *0 byes in /boot*. But I have *not* yet rebooted, so the laptop is still running 16.04, yet wanting a reboot to finish installing 18.04 ... which will *crash* if I do that.

So, is there a way of re-running the install script in place *before* rebooting (now that I have ex-post-facto purged /boot) so that the update will finish cleanly?

I should add that the whole disk is encrypted. Which is particularly why I'm seeking a pre-reboot correction to the broken update.

Comment: You might want to try `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix any broken packages. It should also work after reboot, and if there is no GUI, you can use the recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just boot from a live cd and run Boot-Repair.

Comment: Edited my question to inform that my whole disk is encrypted. So your suggestion, due to my failure to fully inform, is likely to be no solution, I'm now thinking. But I think you nonetheless.

Comment: Have a look at this: this buy rebuilt /boot with an encrypted file system: https://askubuntu.com/questions/844132/how-to-repair-boot-on-luks-encrypted-harddrive/844231