# Upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04 - System no longer boots (boot-repair also not working)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

As the title says, I did `do-release-upgrade` today and have problem now. I've got this computer duel-booted with a win10 disk, and now the Kubuntu 19.10 install is unbootable. The disk has FDE, and even though I've mounted and decrypted my Ubuntu disk, `boot-repair` is not able to fix it, throwing the error `Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature.`

This is the output for `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.68 GiB, 1791954944 bytes, 3499912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000DM003-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 90AA474C-403B-48D8-A51F-EA67103A29E9

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1023999    1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2  1024000    1228799     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1228800    1261567      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1261568 1953523711 1952262144 930.9G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM006-2DM1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xab30ec36

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       2048    1499135    1497088  731M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1501182 3907028991 3905527810  1.8T  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1501184 3907028991 3905527808  1.8T 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdc: 28.96 GiB, 31071404032 bytes, 60686336 sectors
Disk model: USB 3.0 FD      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x48e7426f

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 60686335 60684288  29G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-d5504240-d15c-4453-8767-9beb20b9d785: 1.84 TiB, 1999628140544 bytes, 3905523712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root: 1.84 TiB, 1998602633216 bytes, 3903520768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I attempted to run `boot-repair` once before decrypting it, and that broke it even further. Prior to the first attempt, I got the usual grub-rescue men, however now no OS is detected at all (despite all of my files being there, as I can confirm through the live-usb). I'm not really sure what to do now. I'd really rather *not* reinstall, if possible.

edit: Here is the boot report from `boot-repair`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KSyx5WQtTv/

It seems that if I'm able to open this disk in my live session, it should be possible to fix the problem, since I'm able to see the `/boot` directory in sdb.

Answer (score 0):

Boot-repair is intended to be run from the LiveCD as it says. Make a LiveCD or Live-USB and use that. Or fix boot manually, as detailed in [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub). E.g. Boot through Grub rescue. (Type `ls` to get list of partitions. And then `ls` on each to find one with ext2).

```
set root=(hd0,msdos6)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

And then follow more detailed instructions in the above link for discovering and entering in the details for your particular setup, probably just

```
update-grub /dev/hdb
grub-install
```

(I put /dev/hdb instead of the usual /dev/hda, assuming your output of `fdisk -l` is showing the correct place to put /boot. Or wherever you want to put your Grub boot loader)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by following the solution given here: https://askubuntu.com/a/844231/591650